# How to initialize tf.layers.Conv2D layer with custom weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have built a wrapper around tf.layers.Conv2D. I want to define the layer weights explicitly in the graph as a tensor and then add it to the layer. I want to use the weights multiple times during the training phase.

Something like:

`layer_weights = tf.get_variable(name,shape)`
`x = my_custom_conv_layer(x, weights, args..)`

I want to know what should I write in the build function of the custom layer to set the layer weights to a pre-defined tensor.

I'm writing the Custom Layer following this: 
https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/